# TypeError when using before all hook in ember mocha

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js

I'm running into some issues with the before all hook in `ember-mocha` (version 0.14.0).  Here's an example from [the docs](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-mocha#setup-application-tests) that's been slightly modified to include a `beforeEach` hook:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-mocha';
import { visit, currentURL } from '@ember/test-helpers';

describe('basic acceptance test', function() {
  setupApplicationTest();

  beforeEach(async function() {
    await visit('index');
  });

  it('can visit /', async function() {
    await visit('/');
    expect(currentURL()).to.equal('/');
  });
});
```

The above test runs as expected with no issues. However, when I substitute `before` for `beforeEach` I encounter an error:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-mocha';
import { visit, currentURL } from '@ember/test-helpers';

describe('basic acceptance test', function() {
  setupApplicationTest();

  before(async function() {
    await visit('index');
  });

  it('can visit /', async function() {
    await visit('/');
    expect(currentURL()).to.equal('/');
  });
});
```

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `owner` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at visit (assets/test-support.js:24931:9)
    at Context.<anonymous> (assets/tests.js:339:36)
    at invoke (assets/test-support.js:22801:21)
    at Context.asyncFn (assets/test-support.js:22786:11)
    at callFnAsync (assets/test-support.js:14070:8)
    at Hook.Runnable.run (assets/test-support.js:14022:7)
    at next (assets/test-support.js:14386:10)
    at assets/test-support.js:14408:5
    at timeslice (assets/test-support.js:9651:27)
```

Please let me know if any clarification is needed. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats expected!
`before` only runs once for all tests.
That means before all `beforeEach` hooks
However `setupApplicationTest` utilizes `beforeEach` to setup the app (and the container), and `afterEach` to tear it down again.
This means you get a fresh app for all tests.
However you can not really visit anything without an app.

This means for every test you get a new app instance.
This means there is no app for all tests so there is no app that could visit a route.

---

The same question was asked in the ember discord channel. This answer tries to take the essence of the discussion to archive it on SO.